# What function do I use to make a column in Google sheets produce one sum result each time unlike one total at the end

Tags: google-sheets

Example

Input 5 5 5 5 5

Output 5 10 15 20 25

Disclaimer I know nothing about programming please don’t disperse gibberish to me I just want a copy and pasted function for this with a quick explanation. And I have the row of numbers in the column to the left of it

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take this opportunity to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13196995/daniel-h)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A,MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(A1:A)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A)))*A1:A),SIGN(A1:A)), IFERROR(1/0)))
```

Just substitute the `A1:A` to whatever your data range is. This will give you a running sum of the values in your data set.

If you want to have the output in descending order, use the formula below on your dataset, and then use the first formula on the sorted dataset.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(A1:A)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer back. I put this code you’ve shown me into the formula box and it does come back with results but they are completely random, they aren’t chronologically ordered. Also did I mention, I’m dealing with quite large, random numbers (in descending order) here so it probably needs a different calculation

Comment: @AshtonDowling Could you share a sample version (no sensitive data) of your spreadsheet so I can try to make it work?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/101XejqKHlZaWSJwK7WKZ13bjwY0agpQW3Z3IciLGCa8/edit#gid=0

Comment: I do not have access, please set the sharing preferences to "anyone with the link"

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/101XejqKHlZaWSJwK7WKZ13bjwY0agpQW3Z3IciLGCa8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: See my edited answer, maybe that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for your answer! If I had any spare money I would give it to you because I can't believe that I can get what I want on the internet for free. You've just solved one of my long time problems.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :D Also, if your question has been answered, please mark it as "Answered" with the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm back and after looking at this, I realise that about 40% of the page is just 0. And when i subtract the largest number in column d from the second largest, it is about 400,000 instead of 56,271,872 so there's still something wrong here. And now that I've corrected that 0 thing by adding the number instead of the whole column which contains blank spaces as 0, it starts from 287,253 instead of 7 (the smallest number)

Comment: The formula multiplies every number from column C with the number of the row that number (from column C) is in. e.g. 5 in row 2 will output 10 (5*2=10)  5 in row 3 will output 15 (5*3=15). In your question, that seemed to be what you are looking for. If it is something else that you are looking for, please elaborate on what you need and I will try to solve it for you.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I posted this because I wanted each value in the column to be added on top of each other.

Comment: For example, c column is 5 6 7 8 9 d column is 5 11 18 26 35

Comment: are you just trying to sort the numbers in descending order?

Comment: Oh, okay give me couple minutes

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xanPE1erooxjJjrvmr4YxSUPEgerSx18DtnIcATtcnM/edit#gid=0 here's an update version of the page if you need it

Comment: Access is denied. Nevertheless, see my edited answer

Comment: Other option: allow editing access and I will put the formulas you need in the spreadsheet for you

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xanPE1erooxjJjrvmr4YxSUPEgerSx18DtnIcATtcnM/edit#gid=0

Comment: I just tried it with your dataset but it gave me this error: "the resulting array is too large". Just try doing it bit by bit I guess.

Comment: I'll divide the the column by 10 and remove the decimals